# About the simply-connectedness of algebraic groups

Tags: algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a simply-connected algebraic group. Is it necessarily true that its derived subgroup $G'$ is also simply-connected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is true. The definition of "simply-connected" refers to semisimple algebraic groups (and their classification) over an algebraically closed field: a semisimple algebraic group $G$ is *simply-connected* if every isogeny $G'\rightarrow G$ is an isomorphism. Since a semisimple group is equal to its derived subgroup, the claim is certainly true.
A discussion about simply-connected algebraic groups with some references can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19262/simply-connectedness-of-algebraic-group).

Comment: I Understand this now. Thank you very much.